# Directories converted to files

Tags: linux, filesystems, log-files

Our development team went to start HTTPD and got this:

```
Starting httpd: (20)Not a directory: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Upon investigation we noticed that the `logs` symlink within `/etc/httpd` was a file, OK, so resymlinked. Then noticed that the symlink wasn't the right colour:
[image: Wrong Colours]

So, went to investigate the `/var/log/` folder and found something strange... All of the logs are 0 bytes, all changed at the same time yesterday evening, and all of the log folders that should be folders are now 0 byte files too. See below screenshot for comparison with another (almost identical) server:
[image: Comparison]

Any ideas on what would cause this? It's a virtual machine, and no others have been affected in an even remotely similar way, so I'm not sure that the hardware (which is also new) is failing at this stage.

Comment: Did logrotate go nuts?

Comment: Looks like a buggy script that has messed the whole thing up !

Comment: `logrotate` is running at 04:02, and there are no scripts that are set to run. Even if there were, what would be used to convert a file to a directory other than deleting the dir and `touch`ing the file?

Comment: Typically log files that have been removed are either an operator error or a strong indication that a system is compromised.

Comment: @HBruijn That was my first thought too, until I remembered that it's entirely internal :(

Comment: That still doesn't exclude operator error ;) Nothing in the command history of root and/or people that have login and sudo rights?

Comment: It does, the office was closed at 6 with no remote access and it appeared to happen at 23:45! The history for all accounts is empty!

Comment: You may want to consider running a fsck.  File system corruption can often make files look like directories or symlinks and other oddities.  Be sure to backup or take a snapshot of the VM first.